# Why does executing a command over SSH without a visual terminal use a different PATH location?

Tags: linux, ssh, unix

When executing an SSH session that simply launches a command instead of actually connecting you, it appears as though my PATH environmental variable differs from when I connect to the SSH session normally, and it's missing the location of my binaries for bash commands. Why would this be, and how can I avoid it?

Normal connection of : ssh root@host Yields a PATH env of

> PATH='/sbin:/usr/sbin:/proc/boot'

An ssh to execute command but not connect to the terminal directy (ssh root@host ls) yields "ls: command not found". Upon further inspection, the PATH environmental variable is missing /proc/boot, and thus missing the location of the ls binary file.

The PATH env of this 'non terminal' session yields:

> PATH='/usr/sbin:/sbin'

but NOT /proc/boot, so it can't call standard actions like ls,mkdir, etc.

Why is this? How can I get my proper PATH when simply executing a command over SSH, but not connecting directly to a displayed terminal?

Comment: That is because depending on the session is the type of shell you're using, you can read a little here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50665/what-is-the-difference-between-interactive-shells-login-shells-non-login-shell

and here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell/46856#46856

Comment: Why does your `PATH` have semicolons in it instead of the usual colons?

Comment: Read also about (non-)interactive and (non-)login shells and the different resource/profile settings of your configured default shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because depending on the type of session (login/non-login, interactive/non-interactive) your .profile or your .bashrc are taken in account or not.

To distinguish between the various types of shells, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell).